# Printing the values in a reverse way in java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm working on a question where I need to print the values in a reverse way using for loop in java.  I have tried using the while loop and the for loop but I'm not able to print the values till required.

Please find my code below:

Lets say: y=1000, w=150, z=100;

```
while(y>=w) {
        y-=z;
        System.out.println(y);
    }
```

i need to print the values like:

```
1000
900
800
700 and so on.
```

Kindly help as im new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class reverse {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int start=1000, end=150, decrement=100;
        while(y>=w){
            System.out.println(y);
            y-=z;
        }
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

When i Run the code output is as follows: 
1000
900
800
700
600
500
400
300
200
150

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use 'for' loop when you have decrement or increment operation.
Use 'while' loop if you want to iterate with a condition.

```
int y=1000;
int z=100;
int w=150;

//loop to print values
for(int i=y;i>=w;i-=z)
{
   //print
   System.out.println(i);
}
```